# Delegate and Event which execute/raised first?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, events, delegates

I don't know I should ask this question here or not But anyhow I am asking..

Suppose I have a asp button control, and I am using both Delegate and Click event for that button which will fire first?

On Init:

```
  btn1.Click += delegate{ Save(); };
```

On Click Event:

```
   protected void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
     Save1();
   }
```

I want to know which will execute/raised first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

btn1_click is auto attached with click event in InitializeComponent() function at design time. InitializeComponent(0 function is called from constructor of form. It's default snippet of winforms.

You can not call the following statement before calling the InitializeComponent(), otherwise it will give error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." Till this time the control is not intialised.

```
btn1.Click += delegate{ Save(); };
```

So the order of execution will be first the btn1_Click event and then the save function attached with delegate.

Comment: well yes, I have checked by keeping the break point, Click Event will raise first then deletate Save function.

Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1):

I think it has to do with the order in which they are assigned. Normally a method called btn1_Click will not fire until you bind it either in codebehind or in the ASPX file you are using.

I am guessing you are tying the btn1 to the btn1_Click method in the ASPX, that will probably fire first, but why not just test it? Put breakpoints on both lines and see which is hit first?

Answer (score 0):

Event is not "executed", event is *raised*, so the execution will be of your event-handler which is `btn1_Click` on click esplicitly made by client.